# Eloquent storing form data

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I am currently working on a web application in laravel 4. The essence of the app would be to store form data in a database.

My main problem would be storing the different values in the routines table due to the different names in the form input boxes, as I only have a value field and link that value together with the specified task via id's. I have not found a way to effectively store one row per field in routines.

The database looks like such (ignore Arduino and Endringslogg):

[image: Database model diagram]

HverTimeController.php:

```
class HverTimeController extends BaseController

{
    public $restful = true;

    public function getHvertime()
    {
        return View::make('hvertime')
        ->with('title', 'Hvert Time');
    }

    public function postInsert()
    {


        //insert logic

        return Redirect::route('hvertime')
        ->with('message', 'Lagret i databasen!');


    }
}
```

routes.php

```
Route::get('bassengweb/hvertime', array('as' => 'hvertime', 'uses' => HverTimeController@getHvertime'));
Route::post('bassengweb/insertHT', array('uses' => 'HverTimeController@postInsert'));
```

Eloquent models
(Even though the names in the diagram above are in norwegian, I have since changed them to english in the database as seen in the code below)

Emp.php (Ansatt in diagram)

```
class Emp extends Eloquent
{
    protected $table = 'emps';
    protected $fillable = array(
        'user_name', 'first_name', 
        'last_name', 'email',
        'password', 'user_type');

    public function routines()
    {
        $this->hasMany('Routine', 'emp_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

Routine.php (Rutiner in diagram)

```
class Routine extends Eloquent
{
    protected $table = 'routines';
    protected $fillable = array('date', 'time', 'value', 'emp_id');

    public function emps()
    {
        $this->belongsTo('Emp', 'emp_id', 'id');
    }

    public function tasks()
    {
        $this->belongsToMany('Task', 'task_routine', 'routine_id', 'task_id');
    }

    public function measurements()
    {
        $this->belongsToMany('Measurement', 'measure_routine', 'routine_id', 'measure_id');
    }
}
```

Measurement.php (Målinger table in diagram)

```
class Measurement extends Eloquent
{
    protected $table = 'measurements';
    protected $fillable = array('title');

    public function routines()
    {
        $this->belongsToMany('Routine', 'measure_routine');
    }
}
```

Task.php (Oppgaver table in diagram)

```
class Task extends Eloquent
{
    protected $table = 'tasks';
    protected $fillable = array('title');

    public function routines()
    {
        $this->belongsToMany('Routine', 'task_routine', 'task_id', 'routine_id');
    }
}
```

hvertime.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.default')

@section('content')

    <h1>HVER TIME</h1>

    @if($errors->has())
        <ul>
            {{ $errors->first('badendeTime', '<li>:message</li>') }}
            {{ $errors->first('temp', '<li>:message</li>') }}
        </ul>
    @endif

    {{ Form::open(array('url' => 'bassengweb/insertHT', 'method' => 'POST')) }}
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>{{ Form::label('badendeTime', 'Badende per Time:') }}</td>
                <td>{{ Form::text('badendeTime', Input::old('badendeTime')) }}</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>{{ Form::label('temp', 'Temperatur:') }}</td>
                <td>{{ Form::text('temp', Input::old('temp')) }}</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td><hr/></td>
                <td>{{ Form::submit('Lagre') }}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    {{ Form::close() }}
@stop
```

Any help is much appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Analyzing these relationships

**Oppgaver x OppgaverRutiner x Rutiner**

```
Oppgaver (hasMany) OppgaverRutiner and 
Rutiner (hasMany)  OppgaverRutiner too
```

so the inverse

```
OppgaverRutiner (belongsTo) Oppgaver
OppgaverRutiner (belongsTo) Rutiner
```

**Ansatt x Rutiner**

```
Ansatt (hasMany) Rutiner
```

so the inverse

```
Rutiner (belongsTo) Ansatt
```

**Malinger x MalingerRutiner x Rutiner**

*In table MalingerRutiner is missing foreign key to table Rutiner!!!!!*

```
Malinger (hasMany) MalingerRutiner and
Rutiner (hasMany) MalingerRutiner too
```

the inverse

```
MalingerRutiner (belongsTo)  Malinger
MalingerRutiner (belongsTo) Rutiner
```

**Basseng x MalingerRutiner**

```
Basseng (hasMany) MalingerRutiner
```

the inverse

```
MalingerRutiner (belongsTo)  Basseng
```

You have this logic in your models?

Comment: Hey, yeah that would be the logic in my models, the foreign key from Rutiner in MalingerRutiner is the id row, that's the same as the one in Rutiner.

Comment: @user249494, A good practice would be: [Database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) and [Third normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_normal_form)